# How to get a specific date from the previous month given the current date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the 20th of previous month, given the `current_date()`
I am trying to use `time.strftime` but not able to subtract the value from it.

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-(%m-1)%d")
```

This is giving me error. The expected output is `2019-03-20` if my current_date is in April. Not sure how to go about it.

I read the posts from SO and most of them address getting the first day / last day of the month. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So.. If you can get the first day of the given month, subtract one month, then add 19 days. I'd also suggest using `datetime` as it has more applicable attributes/methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
last_day_prev_month = today - timedelta(days=today.day)
twenty_prev_month = last_day_prev_month.replace(day=20)
print(twenty_prev_month)  # 2019-03-20
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)

```
import datetime

current_date = datetime.date.today()
new_date = current_date.replace(
  month = current_date.month - 1,
  day = 20
)

print(new_date)
#2019-03-20
```

**Edit**

That won't work for Jan so this is a workaround:

```
import datetime

current_date = datetime.date(2019, 2, 17)
month = current_date.month - 1
year = current_date.year
if not month:
  month, year = 12, year - 1

new_date = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=20)
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work for January, for example: `current_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 17)`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it is the way dates are parsed. It is my understanding that with your code it is looking for

`2019-(03-1)20` or `2019-(12-1)15`, etc..

Because the %y is not a variable, but a message about how the date is to be expected within a string of text, and other characters are what should be expected, but not processed (like "-")

This seems entirely not what you are going for. I would just parse the date like normal and then reformat it to be a month earlier:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.today()
print(time)
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
year, month, day = timestr.split("-")
print("{}-{}-{}".format(year, int(month)-1, day))
```

This would be easier with `timedelta` objects, but sadly there isn't one for months, because they are of various lengths.

To be more robust if a new year is involved:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.today()
print(time)
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
year, month, day = timestr.split("-")
if month in [1, "01", "1"]: # I don't remember how January is represented
    print("{}-{}-{}".format(int(year) - 1, 12, day)) # use December of last year
else:
    print("{}-{}-{}".format(year, int(month)-1, day))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

dt = date.today() - timedelta(30)// timedelta(days No.)
print('Current Date :',date.today())
print(dt)
```

Comment: What is `days No.`? This isn't valid syntax and you did not attempt to explain it at all either...

Comment: what happens if the date falls in Feb?

Comment: @Reedinationer Days Number means how many days you want to subtract..Let's say 30 or 31.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do math inside a string passed to `time.strftime`, but you can do something similar to what you're asking very easily using the time module

in Python 3

```
# Last month
t = time.gmtime()
print(f"{t.tm_year}-{t.tm_mon-1}-20")
```

or in Python 2

```
print("{0}-{1}-{2}".format(t.tm_year, t.tm_mon -1, 20))
```

If you have fewer constraints, you can just use the `datetime` module instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find the 20th day of the previous month. See examples below.

---

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```py
from datetime import date

d = date.today()

month, year = (d.month-1, d.year) if d.month != 1 else (12, d.year-1)

last_month = d.replace(day=20, month=month, year=year)

print(last_month)
```

---

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```py
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

d = date.today()

last_month = (d - timedelta(days=d.day)).replace(day=20)

print(last_month)
```

---

Using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta  # pip install python-dateutil

d = date.today()

last_month = d.replace(day=20) - relativedelta(months=1)

print(last_month)
```

---

Using [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```py
import arrow  # pip install arrow

d = arrow.now()

last_month = d.shift(months=-1).replace(day=20).datetime.date()

print(last_month)
```